# Javascript / Coffeescript: Can I pass a variable from current context to a callback function?

Tags: javascript, scope, callback, coffeescript

I am pretty sure this is answered somewhere, but I just can't wrap my head/transfer it. I want to pass a variable from the current context to the context of a callback. I do not want to pass it as parameter.

```
doSomething = (callback) ->
    testVar = 42
    callback()
doSomething -> console.log testVar
```

this compiles to the following JS code

```
var doSomething;
doSomething = function (callback) {
    var testVar;
    testVar = 42;
    return callback();
};
doSomething(function () {
    return console.log(testVar);
});
```

>
`testVar is not defined`

Comment: Yes, you *want* to pass it as a parameter. There's not really a way around this.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a parameter?

Comment: I wantod to create a little module that abstracts away the sourcing of files inside a build task. It had to be an asynchronous operation so I could not just expose a property. On the other hand I wanted to make it as simple as possible through simply exposing the `src` inside the callback.

Comment: Does the user of your module write the complete callback function? Then let them also put a `src` parameter in there, it is simple enough. Do not use magic variables.

Comment: @Bergi you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)You can make closure (works if you have variable and use it in a function at moment of creation)

```
var testVar = 0;
callback = function(){
  console.log(testVar);
}
callback();// prints 0
testVar = 45;
callback();// prints 45
```

2)You can bind variable to function

```
callback = function(testVar){
    console.log(testVar);
}
// first arg will be "this" reference in function, second arg and more will be arguments
callback.bind(this, 45);// will be always until new bind 
callback(); //prints 45
callback(); //prints 45
```

3)You can call variable to function

```
callback = function(testVar){
    console.log(testVar);
}
// first arg will be "this" reference in function, second arg and more will be arguments
callback.call(this, 45);//prints 45 only when you exec call
callback() // prints undefined
```

4) You can call or apply this reference

```
 callback = function(){
    console.log(this);
 }
 // first arg will be "this"
 callback.call(45);//prints 45 only when you exec call
 callback() // prints function ... default this
 callback.bind(45);
 callback(); // prints 45
 callback(); // prints 45
```

Comment: I think that the first solution is not the better one... Avoid side effects while you can !

Comment: Thank you, but I was unable to transfer this to my specific scenario. The question was updated. If you can post a code example structured like mine that would be great, but I solved the problem differently already.